# R Markdown to PDF conversion error

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am converting a long file from .rmd to .pdf

But when I try to *knit* it, it always shows this error:

```
   Error in pls::mvr(form, ncomp = ncomp, data = DCVf, validation = "none",  : 
   Invalid number of components, ncomp
```

Before this error, this line is prompted:

```
Quitting from lines 395-690 (a.Rmd)
```

and on this line this is the code:-

```
After this, once these libraries are included:-
```

`{r}
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(leaps)
library(caret)
library(bestglm)
library(glmnet)
library(pls)`

````
we can obtain our analysis in the following manner:
```{r}

prostate = prostate
index = createDataPartition(prostate$lpsa, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train <- prostate[ index,]
test  <- prostate[-index,]
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the issue was. As I didn't intended the code to run and it wouldn't have runned anyways - I should've surrounded the code with

````
```
code
```
````

instead of

````
```{r}
code
```
````

Once again, the error was appearing since in order for the code to run, many requisites had to be resolved. Once I did the above replacement, my document *knitted* easily.

PS:

````
```{r}
code
```
````

is only used when we want to execute the code.